# Does anyone know why this writing to .txt file doesn't work?

Tags: python, text-files

When I run this code and input values for `crop` and `quantity` it doesn't write them to `crop database.txt` like it should, but just creates `crop database.txt` as a new blank text file. Does anyone know why this is? Is it because of the way I am closing the file?

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")

with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:

 lines = file.readlines()

file.close ()

with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:

 for row in lines:

    if crop in row:

       row = str(a)
       split_2 = a.split (',')
       split_2.append (quantity)

    else:

       file.write ('\n')
       file.write (crop + ' ')
       file.write (quantity + ' ')

file.close ()
```

Comment: When using `with` you do not need to close the file explicitly. It is automatically closed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Code for writing looks OK I think, have you tried some print statements to make sure crop and quantity are initialized and that you ever go into the else block of your if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with comments:

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")
```

If you are using python 2, this is a bad idea.  use raw_input

```
with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:
```

You are opening this file to append, but are just reading it

```
 lines = file.readlines()

file.close ()
```

You don't need to close since you used 'with open'

```
with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:
```

Once again  you open to append.  You should rewrite the file with 'w'

```
 for row in lines:

    if crop in row:

       row = str(a)
       split_2 = a.split (',')
       split_2.append (quantity)
```

This makes no sense to me.  What is a?
After mucking with split2 (again, why) you never write anything

```
    else:

       file.write ('\n')
       file.write (crop + ' ')
       file.write (quantity + ' ')
```

Now you write crop and quantity to lines that don't have a match?

```
file.close ()
```

again, unnecessary close

here is my code

```
crop = raw_input("Which crop? ")
quantity = raw_input("How many? ")
```

using raw_input, both will be strings

```
with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Read the complete file into lines, then close it (automatically)

```
with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'w') as file:
    for row in lines:
        if crop in row:
            row = row.strip(), ", ", quantity
            file.write(row)
```

You don't specify, so I am writing the row that matches crop and adding the quantity after a comma

```
        else:
            file.write(row)
```

Try this and come back with what you see.  First save your input file to another name so you can compare the two

Answer (score 1):

If you start with an empty file (or non-existing) the list `lines` will be empty. So your code for writing anything never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha small bug.

- use open(filename, 'r') for reading a file
- use open(filename, 'a') for appending some data to a exsisting file
- use open(filename, 'w') for creating/re-writing a file.

when you open a file with appending 'a', state the file pointer is placed just before EOF(end of file) pointer. So you wont be reading any data.

I would prefer nt using 'a+', it looks great but using a specific format gives more clarity for reading code.

try this

```
with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'r') as file:

   lines = file.readlines()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to use raw_input

```
crop = raw_input("Which crop? ")
quantity = raw_input("How many? ")
```

Then you do not need f.close() because you have with open.